# Need a DC-DC SSR that can allow a system to either charge or discharge

Tags: solid-state-relay

I acquired a Crydom HDC100D160 and it seems it wont be appropriate for my application due to it's single-stage MOSFET:
[image]

My application will be a controller that can signal the SSR to disconnect a battery from a solar system, where when connected, then at some times the solar system can charge the battery and at other times the battery can provide power to the solar system.

Now it does appear that there are other types of SSRs with dual FET output (I believe the
Omron G3VM & Toshiba TLP172A are like this, but they are too small for my application).

My application is for a 12vdc signal to the SSR that will switch 72vDC @ 135amps.

Are there other DC in/out SSRs out there that can support my power specs and allow both charging and discharging?

ALTERNATIVELY, I could settle for operation with a single state FET on the output if when the SSR is turned off, that it only prevents the solar system from charging the battery, but that even though the SSR is off that current could still flow from the battery to the solar system.  Would the existing Crydom that I have be able to do that?

EDIT:  No it is not AC on the output side, my application is for DC for both sides.  The output side will connect between the battery and the inverter.  The *other* side of the inverter is where the AC is.

Comment: What you need is an AC SSR. You have an AC signal, after all. (DC control input, AC switch "contacts", with dual anti-serial MOSFETs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current through the SSR *alternates* between flowing from the battery to the solar system, and vice-versa. The voltage across the SSR also alternates between two polarities (the solar system side has a higher voltage when charging, and a lower voltage when discharging, with respect to the battery). You really do have an AC signal, at least as far as the SSR is concerned. Use an AC SSR (a dual MOSFET type, not a triac-based one).

You can also build your own AC SSR with two discrete MOSFETs and a photovoltaic optocoupler (I like the ASSR-V621-002E, but it seems to have become unobtainable).

The fact that you have a DC battery system doesn't mean that some voltages and currents in it can't still be AC, even if it's very low frequency AC (i.e. a current that reverses once per day).

Comment: I understand now, thanks - I would think that if I were to try to use an AC output model as you suggest then not only would it have to be dual-mosfet based instead of thyristor, but it would also have to be the 'random' start type, no zero crossing, etc?

Im not so sure what I need even exists as I cant seem to find any mosfet/random that also can handle 160 watts.  I understand Ill need to overrate it by 1.7x as well since Im talking about using DC current in the device spec'ed for AC amps?

Comment: It's correct that you'll need a "random start" SSR without zero-cross detection. Current derating should not be necessary, at least not because you're operating it with a DC current instead of AC. You might have to derate for temperature, though. If you can't find one that's big enough, you can always build your own.

Comment: To give some actual part suggestions: Anti-serial IRF150P220AKMA1 as the switching MOSFETs (maybe two in parallel each, four in total), TLP3910 as the isolated gate driver, and a 18V zener to limit the gate voltage. (The zener diode has to be specified at low current - around 10µA. It has to have low leakage below the breakdown voltage.)

Comment: OK, as far as building my own, is it really as simple as https://www.instructables.com/Make-Your-Own-Solid-State-Relay/  (I understand Ill have 3 more MOSFETs though)

Comment: It really is that simple, see for example figure 4 here: https://www.bristolwatch.com/ele3/1g.htm For safety, add a zener diode on the gate if you use the TLP3910 (its output voltage might otherwise get too high and damage the MOSFET gate). Also, keep in mind that the MOSFETs will need a very good cooling solution if you really want to operate them at 135A. (The instructables link you posted is for a triac-based SSR, which is not what you want)

Comment: And alternatively to building, should I elect to use that existing Crydom HDC100D160 that I have, I do believe that I would be able to wire it up such that when the SSR is engaged that the SSR will allow current to flow from the inverter tp the battery.  And when the SSR is not engaged the inverter cannot charge the battery.

BUT, that regardless of the state of the SSR's input power, current would always be able to flow from the battery to the inverter?

I think I have that correct, but is that all "safe"?

Comment: No, you can't let current flow through the SSR in reverse when it's off. It will destroy the SSR. The entire load current will flow through the internal MOSFET's body diode, which might drop up to 2V at 135A for a total power dissipation of 270W. The SSR will fail quite spectacularly if it ever operates under these conditions. (I'd suggest you to wear a face shield and protective clothing if you decide to try it anyway.)